# How can I contribute to FreeDB

Tags: cd

I want to add Data to the FreeDB CD database. So I have a CD wih titles etc that is still not available on FreeDB. What tool can I use to write the titles and post it to the FreeDB?

There is the [FAQ](http://www.freedb.org/en/faq.3.html#21) that states to take Grip for Linux. But Grip is no longer available in the Ubuntu packages. There are [these other applications](http://www.freedb.org/en/applications__freedb_aware_applications.9.html) as well:  But non of them can be found in Ubuntu packages or they are very heavy weighted tools like Jack that I would not like to install just for this simple task.

Further, the FAQ and the list looks very outdated, so there might be any better solutions that are not to find there?

Comment: I think you mean FreeDB perhaps? Freenode is an IRC (chat) network.

Comment: If it is FreeDB http://www.freedb.org/en/faq.3.html#21 section 2.1 has what you want to know

Comment: of course that was meant :) sorry, I corrected it and updated the question to your comments as well

Answer (score 0):

For instance k3b supports freedb (and MusicBrainz):
[image: k3b cddb config tab]

By default k3b will submit to freedb when you add a new CD.

If you run `apt-cache search cddb` you'll get a list of packages mentioning cddb. It may be worth to have a look at a few of these as well.

Comment: most of the result of `apt-cache search cddb` will be rippers that GET data from freeDB

Comment: Yes, but some rippers additionally supports submitting information. k3b is such a case.